# Format numbers in jTextField

Tags: java, user-interface, formatting

Learning Java. I have a made a GUI app.
Tax calculator of sorts.
I have a textfield where the user enters a number, say 1000000.
I want that number formatted to 1,000,000 after the user has exited the field.
How can can I pull it off?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. It has helped me.